# Ошибка в решении задачи "Странный+"

Tags: javascript

> Задайте переменную `str1` и присвойте ей значение строки 'Everything'.
>
> Задайте переменную `str2` и присвойте ей значение строки 'is'.
>
> Задайте переменную `str3` и присвойте ей значение строки 'beautiful'.
>
> Задайте переменную `message` и присвойте ей результат слияния
>   переменных str1, str2 и str3 с разделителем - пробелом и
>   восклицательным знаком в конце.

Пример:

```
const x = 'best'; const y = 'day'; const res = x + ' ' + y;
```

Моё решение:

```
const str1 = 'Everything';
const str2 = 'is';
const str3 = 'beautiful';
const message = str1 + ' ' + str2 + ' ' + str3;
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

> expected 'Everything is beautiful' to equal 'Everything is beautiful!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыли в конце `!` поставить:

```
const message = str1 + ' ' + str2 + ' ' + str3 + '!';
```

Comment: Добавил '!' в конце действительно всё получилось! const message = str1 + ' ' + str2 + ' ' + str3 + '!'; Эх новичком быть непросто;)

Comment: @SergeyfromKhabarovsk Ну, тут это скорее из-за невнимательного чтения условия задачи.

Comment: @SergeyfromKhabarovsk Отметьте ответ галочкой